# Retrieve only one field from object/array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

In ruby I'm able to do the following:

```
myObject.map(&:name)
```

And I get an array composed by all the `name` field for all values inside `myObject` (array or object).

What's the underscore.js or lodash.js equivalent? I prefer in only one line if possible :)

*Example*: (in js)

```
_.map([{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}], function(obj){
    //dosomething
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
_.pluck([{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}],"name");
```

this will give you: ["x","y"];

see http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Comment: using .map you can do: _.map({name: "x", name: "y"}, function(i, o){ return o.name; });

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that one ^^

Comment: It's the little things :). Wouldn't mind if you accepted as answer

Comment: You were too fast for SO.I have to wait 2 minutes :p

Answer (score 3):

For *lodash* users,

```
_.map([{'name': 'x'}, {'name': 'y'}], 'name');

// ['x', 'y']
```

Comment: Note that they had `pluck` but removed it to only use `map`. But `pluck` did exist back in the time and may exist depending on your version. Regardless, `map` is always available in every version so I'd say it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Using pure `Javascript` simply use `map`

```
let data = [{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}];
data.map( (item) => item.name );
```

Will return you `["x", "y"]`.

Comment: very very nice 